# How to remove duplicate emoticaons in given text

Tags: python

I would like to know whether there is n approach to extract district emoticons

```html
import emoji
import regex as re
orig_list = ['Get ❤️❤️ extracted,  are  in this  this  text.❤️❤️']
emojis_iter = map(lambda y: y, emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI['en'].keys())
regex_set = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(em) for em in emojis_iter))
newlist = re.findall(r'[^\w\s,.]', orig_list[0])
print(newlist)
```

Comment: The question is very ambiguous. Do you want to remove duplicate emoticons as it says in the title? Do you want to extract distinct (I guess that's what you mean by "district") emoticons as it says in the question itself? Please clarify and include your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

For removing duplicate emoji, I would recommend you use simple for-loop
to resolve this problem.

```py
import emoji

emoji_string = "Get ❤️❤️ extracted,  are  in this  this  text.❤️❤️"


def remove_duplicate_emoji(orig_str):
    prev_emoji = None
    remove_duplicate_emoji = []
    for c in orig_str:
        if c in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI_ENGLISH:
            if prev_emoji == c:
                continue
            prev_emoji = c
        remove_duplicate_emoji.append(c)
    return "".join(remove_duplicate_emoji)


print(remove_duplicate_emoji(emoji_string))
# "Get ❤️ extracted,  are  in this  this  text.❤️"
```

If you really want to get the list of duplicated emoji, you can also change a bit on the code above to return a list.